# Upgrading from 1.8 to 1.9 Django Admin get_urls not working

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am using the Django admin and have just upgraded from 1.8 to 1.9. In 1.8, I added a click button to the change_form that takes me to another html template using the get_urls override. Like this:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(arunAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        (r'(\d+)/tarrespgraph/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.tarrespgraph)),
        )
return my_urls + urls
```

Following some of the recommendations I saw online, I have changed this to:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(arunAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^tarrespgraph/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.tarrespgraph)),
    ]        
    return my_urls + urls
```

But am receiving this error:

NBI Graph object with primary key '132/change/tarrespgraph' does not exist.

Django finds the customized change_form.html without a problem. My custom template (tarrespgraph.html) is in the same folder as my customized change_form.html. Where is Django looking for my custom template? Should I move the tarrespgraph.html, or change the reference to the url? Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Based on your code, i dont know how this was working earlier. But it looks like in the new state you do not have the pattern to accept the `\d+`. Also, that does not still account for the `/change/` in the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't have removed the `(\d+)` group from your url pattern. Try the following:

```
my_urls = [
    url(r'^(\d+)/tarrespgraph/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.tarrespgraph), name='tarrespgraph'),
]
```

Note that I've added a name, which will let us reverse the url later.

Without the `(\d+)` group, the new url pattern does not match the url, so it is handled by the admin change view which gives the error.

You also need to change the link in your template. In Django 1.9, Django has appended `change` to the admin change url (e.g it is now `/admin/app/model/132/change/` instead of `/admin/app/model/132/`. That means that your relative link `'tarrespgraph/'` now points to `/admin/app/model/132/change/tarrespgraph/` instead of `/admin/app/model/132/tarrespgraph/`. You could change the relative link to `../tarrespgraph/`. However, it would be less fragile to use the `url` tag instead:

```
<a class="tarrespgraph" href="{% url 'admin:tarrespgraph' object_id %}">
```

Comment: I tried adding it back (as you indicated above), but I still get the error.

Comment: In 1.8, Django did not add the two /change/ to the url, and I do not know how it is using those in hunting for the template, but is definitely behaving differently.

Comment: By trial and error, I found that this works: url(r'^(\d+)/change/tarrespgraph/change/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.tarrespgraph)),

Comment: As I said, Django 1.9 has changed the url of the change view to include `change/` at the end (see [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#django-contrib-admin)). I am not sure where the second 'change' is coming from, because you haven't show how you are linking to the page in your template. You shouldn't need to use `r'^(\d+)/change/tarrespgraph/change/$` instead of `r'^(\d+)/tarrespgraph/$` unless you prefer that.

Comment: With regard to the rest of what you mentioned, at the top of my arunAdmin class, I have this: tarrespgraph_template = 'admin/nbig/arun/tarrespgraph.html' and then, I have a function defined in my arunAdmin class called def tarrespgraph(self, request, id). At the end of that function, I use render to response like this:  return render_to_response(self.tarrespgraph_template, {........... In the change_form.html, I have added a click button like this: <a class="tarrespgraph" href="tarrespgraph/">{% trans "Click HERE to see target response rate graphs." %}</a>

Comment: You need to change the link in the template. See my updated answer. Remember to add the name to the url pattern.

Comment: Alasdair, Thanks for taking the time to look at this so thoroughly. I did what you suggested (I think). I changed the line in the change_form.html to <a class="tarrespgraph" href="{% url 'tarrespgraph' object_id %}">{% trans "Click HERE to see target response rate graphs." %}</a> and I changed the line in the admin.py to url(r'^(\d+)/tarrespgraph/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.tarrespgraph), name='tarrespgraph'), and now I get this error:  
Reverse for 'tarrespgraph' with arguments '('132',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: I forgot the namespace. Try `{% url 'admin:tarrespgraph' object_id %}`.